# CSS selector to target all `<li>` elements that are not descendants of `<li>`

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example, given the following HTML

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I need a CSS selector that targets `<li>First</li>` and `<li>Second</li>`.

I tried

```
:not(li) li {
  declarations
}
```

but that matches `<li>A</li>` and `<li>B</li>` as well because while each does have an `<li>` as a descendant, each also has a non-`<li>` in their descendant list: `[<body>, <ul>, <li>, <ul>]`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. The nested `<ul>` should be inside an `<li>`. Fixed and updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `li:not(li li)`

```css
li:not(li li) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li> <!-- this will get selected -->
      <ul>
        <li>A</li> <!-- but not this -->
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct selector is:

```
body > ul > li {
  declarations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not going to have more li elements under first ul, you can do it like this:

```
  ul li:not(li ul li):first-child {
        border: 1px solid #435643;
      }
      ul li:not(li ul li):last-child {
      border: 1px solid #435643;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Write just

body ul > li {...}